# Document sharing and revoking access in corda

Tags: corda

How can we share & unshare documents (pdf) in corda? Actually i am looking for something where documents can be shared and then revoked later. similar to this in video.
https://marketplace.r3.com/solutions/dreamzchain-kyc

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/manosbatsis/corda-kyc-app), the repo hasn't been updated for 3 years though; but maybe you can find something that helps you start writing your own CorDapp.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to take look at the Blue Catalyst project by Capgemini: https://www.bluecatalyst.io/ 
They are the most up to date KYC projects that we have worked with.